# How can i draw in picturebox a polygon which is marked on the edges

Tags: c#, draw, polygon, point

i tried in that way but i didnt get the needed results:

```
System.Drawing.Point[] p = new System.Drawing.Point[6];
p[0].X = 0;
p[0].Y = 0;
p[1].X = 53;
p[1].Y = 111;
p[2].X = 114;
p[2].Y = 86;
p[3].X = 34;
p[3].Y = 34;
p[4].X = 165;
p[4].Y = 7;
g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawPolygon(pen1, p);
```

what i want to do is to draw a polygon in picturebox which is defined with diffrent colors and according to the rates (the number of corner and coordinates of the edges )

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create an xOffset variable, set it to be 30, and add that to every X value.
Let yOffset equal 50 and add it to all your Ys.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this to your graphics object:

```
g.TranslateTransform(30, 40);
```

before drawing onto it.

And of course you shouldn't use `PictureBox1.CreateGraphics();` but draw things you want to **persist** in the `Paint` event with `e.Graphics` !..