# Drawing a polygon according to the input coordinates

Tags: c#, draw, polygon

How can i draw a polygon according to the input coordinates which are given in C#.

[image]

Comment: What type of application ? winform wpf

Comment: @Habib, looking at his screenshot, that's winforms

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't show any code because based on those coordinate, you are applying some form of scaling to the image.

Using the Paint event of a PictureBox, here is an example using those coordinates on the screen.  It fills in the polygon, then draws the border, then it loops through all the points to draw the red circle:

```
void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

  // draw the shading background:
  List<Point> shadePoints = new List<Point>();
  shadePoints.Add(new Point(0, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height));
  shadePoints.Add(new Point(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, 0));
  shadePoints.Add(new Point(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,
                            pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height));
  e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.LightGray, shadePoints.ToArray());

  // scale the drawing larger:
  using (Matrix m = new Matrix()) {
    m.Scale(4, 4);
    e.Graphics.Transform = m;

    List<Point> polyPoints = new List<Point>();
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(10, 10));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(12, 35));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(22, 35));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(24, 22));

    // use a semi-transparent background brush:
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow))) {
      e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, polyPoints.ToArray());
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkBlue, polyPoints.ToArray());

    foreach (Point p in polyPoints) {
      e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 
                             new Rectangle(p.X - 2, p.Y - 2, 4, 4));
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Graphics.DrawPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can store the coordinates in an array of Point and then you can pass that to DrawPolygon method. You may wanna see:

[Drawing with Graphics in WinForms using C#](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/winforms-drawing-cs.aspx)

```
private System.Drawing.Graphics g;
System.Drawing.Point[] p = new System.Drawing.Point[6];
p[0].X = 0;
p[0].Y = 0;
p[1].X = 53;
p[1].Y = 111;
p[2].X = 114;
p[2].Y = 86;
p[3].X = 34;
p[3].Y = 34;
p[4].X = 165;
p[4].Y = 7;
g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawPolygon(pen1, p);
```

Comment: In WinForms, the control coordinates start at the upper left corner, so you will need to translate them to the lower left corner.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to see my polygon's corner points diffrent shape or color.. And this code isn't useful. i have corner points and i try to draw a polygon like corner points diffrent . i hope i can tell my problem.. ( [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081978/how-can-i-draw-in-picturebox-a-polygon-which-is-marked-on-the-edges) this is my privies question..)

Comment: @Mehmet, for that you have to draw a circle for each point in the array. You may use `DrawEllipse` method for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

This simple function is able to generate an array of PointF equal to the vertices of the regular polygon to be drawn, where "center" is the center of the polygon, "sides" is its number of sides, "sideLength" is the size of each side in pixels and "offset" is its slope.

```
public PointF[] GetRegularPolygonScreenVertex(Point center, int sides, int sideLength, float offset)
{
    var points = new PointF[sides];

    for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new PointF(
            (float)(center.X + sideLength * Math.Cos((i * 360 / sides + offset) * Math.PI / 180f)),
            (float)(center.Y + sideLength * Math.Sin((i * 360 / sides + offset) * Math.PI / 180f))
        );
    }

    return points;
}
```

The result obtained can be used to draw a polygon, e.g. with the function:

```
GraphicsObject.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Brushes.Black, GetRegularPolygonScreenVertex(new Point(X, Y), 6, 30, 60f));
```

Which will generate a regular hexagon with a side of 30 pixels inclined by 30°.
[hex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAUc2.png)