# draw polygon click area

Tags: c#, click, picturebox

[Drawing a polygon according to the input coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108534/drawing-a-polygon-according-to-the-input-coordinates)

i got some code from here, i just take..

```
void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    List<Point> polyPoints = new List<Point>();
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(30, 30));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(36, 105));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(66, 105));
    polyPoints.Add(new Point(72, 66));

    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, polyPoints.ToArray());
    }
    e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkBlue, polyPoints.ToArray());
}
```

note : `SmoothingMode` use header `using System.Drawing.Drawing2D`

then i got problem about click area, i just want the click area at the visible area, in this case the `picturebox1` have size 1366 x 768

[image: the example polygon in picturebox]

this is example of `picturebox`, i want the red area be clickable and the gray is not clickable area
by default all area in the box is clickable

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Documentation on [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

I'm looking at it and it seems there's many ways of resizing aspects of the PixtureBox object. Take a look at using the [DefaultSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.defaultsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or setting the Size property. In either case, you have to wrap the size in a Size object and set the according PictureBox size property.

Such as:

```
pictureBox1.Size = new Size(xSize, ySize);
```

or

```
pictureBox1.DefaultSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
```

Comment: sorry it's not the problem, i have problem with `mouse_click` event not the size of `picturebox`

Comment: Oh, my apologies. Well, if that's the case couldn't you just cross reference the position of the mouse with the position of the window and any objects within the window?

Comment: it's okay :) no problem