# Drawing a polygon on the form

Tags: c#, drawing, polygons

I would like to draw a polygon on the form but i would like to add polygon positions by mouse click.

Right now i gave the constant (x,y) positions and it returns me a polygon,But i would like to add those position by clicking mouse.

```
 Point[] po = new Point[]
            {

                new Point {X=15, Y=51},
                new Point {X=40, Y= 13},
                new Point {X=87, Y= 53},
                new Point {X=56, Y= 87},
                new Point {X=44, Y= 32},
            };
```

Comment: There are many questions, and sources available for receiving mouse clicks. What have you already tried? Have you actually tried to find a solution? Are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: Here is a example code i think this can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108534/drawing-a-polygon-according-to-the-input-coordinates

Comment: i try to let the user draw a polygon by mouse click and i would use it to determine region of interest on the form  @Ben

Comment: Use  the MouseClick and collect the e.Locations in a List<Point>! Use the Paint event to e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.black, yourList.ToArray());

Comment: @Tom: That link lumps collecting the points and drawing them into the same (Paint) event. That is nonsense here as the question does ask for an interactive solution. -  Instead the former goes into the MouseClick and only drawing into the Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

create a customcontrol for draw Polygon:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class DrawPolygon : Control
{
    ObservableCollection<PointF> points;
    public int SideCount
    {
        get { return sideCount; }
        set { sideCount = value; }
    }

    public DrawPolygon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        points = new ObservableCollection<PointF>();
        points.CollectionChanged += Points_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Points_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        if (points.Count >= sideCount)
            {
                points = new ObservableCollection<PointF>(points.Skip(points.Count - sideCount));
                points.CollectionChanged += Points_CollectionChanged;
            }
        Refresh();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        points.Add(e.Location);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
        if (points.Count > 1)
            pe.Graphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Aqua, points.ToArray());

    }
}
```

}

After build, you can add it from toolbox to your form.

This is a sample of result:[Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CSIc.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like overkill and still won't allow overlapping Polygons. A Polygon class seems more appropriate.